# Why can't 'sbt run' find reference.conf in the standard location?

Tags: java, sbt, akka, typesafe-config

I have reference.conf in src/main/resources/reference.conf

After I compile, I can see it in target/scala-2.12/classes/reference.conf but when I do 'sbt run' it does not pick it up.

When I run my app from IntelliJ IDEa, it can find it.

As far as I can tell from all the documentation, SBT should do the right thing because these are all defaults. I can only assume SBT is broken. Should I open an issue on this?

Also, when doing

```
sbt 'inspect run' 'show runtime:fullClasspath'
```

I can see `target/scala-2.12/classes` on my classpath, so I cannot understand why reference.conf is not being seen?

Comment: Are you writing a library? I typically only use application.conf because ConfigFactory.load will merge these configs and anything specified in application.conf will have higher precedence

Comment: Nope, I just like to put a reference.conf in my Akka server for default settings, and documentation purposes.

Comment: I created a small sample project with only `akka.loglevel` set in `reference.conf` and it appears to be working OK.

Comment: Could you please, provide more information? Screenshot or for example, your typed commands, sbt version, your project structure, your sbt edit confuguration in intellij. It looks like, there is correct path, but when you run sbt, there is no. Also, did you try to enter 'clean' and 'cleanFiles' commands in sbt console ? But I'm not sure in my tips, please give more info, if you want me to help you. Thank you.

Comment: Okay, now it seems to be working. The only thing different I did this times was after `sbt clean` I did `sbt cleanFiles` - thanks. While I very much appreciate the help, I find it disconcerting that I had so much trouble with this, when it has always worked before.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments to my question, the solution seems to be

```
sbt clean
sbt cleanFiles
```